# How to delete/modify the same part of a record (pattern) that presents in multiple records?

Tags: mysql

I have got a question - how do I delete the same pattern (2-3 symbols) that presents in multiple records in the same position.

So far, I have managed to find out this query returns me the required result but it does not actually modify the records in the required way (it does not delete the pattern from the records).

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(column_name,1,length(column_name)-2) 
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name LIKE '%symbols'
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: For example....

Comment: It looks better now, right. Thank you. Sorry for the mess. But it does not answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using the [REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html) statement

```
UPDATE
    table_name
SET
    column_name = REPLACE(column_name, 'pattern', '')
WHERE
    column_name LIKE '%pattern';
```